# How to change color of floating action button on theme change ? in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, themes, floating-action-button, flutter-getx

How to change color of floating action button on theme change ? in flutter and also How can I find out what the current theme is in the app? in flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Current theme

```
ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
```

To change Theme

```
    ThemeData(
//to change primary color
primarySwatch: Colors.red,


//to change only floating action button theme

          floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
        
             backgroundColor: ,
             foregroundColor: ,  
          ),
       );
```

to get current device theme is  Dark theme or not

```
final brightnessValue = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness;
            bool isDark = brightnessValue == Brightness.dark;
```

Answer (score 0):

In ThemeData you have the floatingActionButtonTheme property

```
   ThemeData(
      floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
         focusColor: ,
         hoverColor: ,
         splashColor: ,
         backgroundColor: ,
         foregroundColor: ,  
      ),
   );
```

Theme is declare in MaterialApp, in theme property